# Running 64bit guest on top of 32 host (Windows/Linux)

Tags: windows, virtualbox, 64-bit, x86

Is it possible to run 64-bit guest OS (linux/BSD), using VirtualBox on 64-bit capable CPU, but when host OS is 32bit? (Host may be linux or windows.)

Will 64bit guest run at full speed or it will be slow (64-bit wide instructions emulated like in qemu)?

If 64bit guest will be full speed, is there some 64-bit microOS inside virtualbox? There should be 64-bit host OS to correctly switch between 32 and 64 bit code.

This question is raised because I want to run several virtualized 64-bit Oses and do a highload test between them.

Comment: Why can't you run a 64 bit OS on the host?  You can probably make it work, but you'll be severely restricted in a number of important ways (like the maximum memory available to each guest).

Comment: This just doesn't seem like a good idea, let alone I've never heard of it being possible, especially on VMware or MSFT.

Comment: When you typed in your question title millions of CPU cycles leapt into action to list for your personal selection a range of previously asked questions based on what you typed - you chose to ignore them all and the effort that went into allowing your that luxury, preferring instead to waste everyone's time. Shame on you.

Comment: Chopper3, Can you provide a link to the related question? I can't find any question about 32bit host and 64bit virtualbox guest in this list (just rechecked).

Answer (score 2):

From the Virtualbox 2.1.2 User Guide, section 1.6:

> 64-bit guests
>
> Starting with Version 2.0, VirtualBox also supports 64-bit guest operating systems.
>
> Starting with Version 2.1, you can even run 64-bit guests on a 32-bit host operating system, so long as you have sufficient hardware.
>
> In detail, 64-bit guests are supported under the following conditions:
>
> 1. You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see chapter
>        1.2, Software vs. hardware virtualization (VT-x and AMD-V), page 10).
> 2. You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for which you
>        want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.
>        Note: On most systems, the hardware virtualization features first need to be
>        enabled in the BIOS before VirtualBox can use them.
> 3. If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, you
>        must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM. Since supporting
>        64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this
>        support upon explicit request.
>
> On 64-bit hosts, 64-bit guest support is always enabled, so you can simply install a 64-bit operating system in the guest.

Still seems like a dumb idea.

Comment: How big is the "additional overhead" from "3."?

Comment: Variable.  Like asking how many resources your OS uses.